# how to get CGSizes of image urls in NSArray

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsarray, cgsize

I have a `NSArray` which contains `NSString`s of image urls like so:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/07/22/blogs/20140722-lens-mark-slide-SG5C/20140722-lens-mark-slide-SG5C-custom1.jpg", @"http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/07/22/blogs/20140722-lens-mark-slide-SG5C/20140722-lens-mark-slide-SG5C-custom2.jpg", @"http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/07/22/blogs/20140722-lens-mark-slide-6N62/20140722-lens-mark-slide-6N62-blog480.jpg", nil];
```

How do I get the `CGSize` of each `imageUrl`?

I know how to get the size of one imageUrl like so:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/07/22/blogs/20140722-lens-mark-slide-SG5C/20140722-lens-mark-slide-SG5C-jumbo.jpg"]]];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
```

Comment: «Two or more, use a for»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(NSString *stringURL in array)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]]];
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
}
```

I would not suggest doing it in main thread.

If you want to get array of sizes you should do the following:

```
NSMutableArray *sizes = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *stringURL in array)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]]];
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    [sizes addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:imageSize];
}
```

After that you can get `CGSize` in the following way:

```
CGSize imageSize = [sizes[index] CGSizeValue];
```

Comment: you should add the size to an array

Comment: I can use NSValue for this. But it was not part of question.

Comment: How do you know? he asks to get the values from an array, but you code will only return the latest value.

Comment: Because I do not see it in question. My code will not return any value because imageSize is visible only inside loop.

Comment: so you agree that your code doesn't make much sense at all?

Comment: I agree that my post is just an answer for the question. I've updated my post for you :)

Comment: well, we can assume that OP wants to do something with the sizes, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57836/discussion-between-sviatoslav-yakymiv-and-vikingosegundo).

Comment: no, I am just about to leave. +1 for a complete answer